# What is the execution order of Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

The json below is an example in https://www.elastic.co/blog/top-hits-aggregation/

```
{
   "query":{
      "match":{
         "body":"web"
      }
   },
   "size":1,
   "aggs":{
      "top-programming-languages":{
         "terms":{
            "field":"tags",
            "include":"java|javascript|python|php|python|ruby|perl|c#",
            "size":10,
            "order":{
               "max_score":"desc"
            }
         },
         "aggs":{
            "top-questions":{
               "top_hits":{
                  "size":1
               }
            },
            "max_score":{
               "max":{
                  "lang":"expression",
                  "script":"doc.score"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I just cannot understand the logic here.

Firstly the following query is executed, and only one result is returned.

```
   "query":{
      "match":{
         "body":"web"
      }
   },
   "size":1,
```

Then the following `top-programming-languages` aggregation just operates on this one single record?

And in the `top-programming-languages -> term -> order`, `max_score` is require, but it doesn't exist until the `top-programming-languages -> aggs -> max_score` aggregation is completed. Then how is it possible that `top-programming-languages -> term` can be executed?

It seems that ES uses a counter-intuition execution order, but I failed to find the explanation in its documentation.

Could someone help me here?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query is executed and matches N documents.

From those N documents, only one is returned, i.e. the one with the highest score (since it's a `match` query, so a ranked one).

Then, the aggregations are run on **all the N documents** (i.e. not only on the one being returned) that are matched by the query and the `tags` are aggregated from all those documents.

On each shard of your index, the tags are bucketed and ordered in such a way that the ones that contain documents with the highest `doc.score` come first. For each bucket, the top document is surfaced in the `top-questions` sub-aggregation. Finally, the top 10 buckets of each shard are returned to the coordinating node. However, since you only include 7 tags (python is listed twice), there might only be 7 buckets per shard.

The coordinating node then combines them together and reorders all the tags buckets from all the shards according to `max_score` and only take the first 10 buckets.

Let's say your index has 2 shards and the following documents (and to make it simpler I'm going to take `size: 5` instead of 10, because your `include` clause conflicts with size 10):

Shard 1:

```
{"body":"web", "score": 1, "tags": "java"}
{"body":"web", "score": 2, "tags": "c#"}
{"body":"web", "score": 10, "tags": "javascript"}
{"body":"web", "score": 3, "tags": "python"}
{"body":"web", "score": 2, "tags": "php"}
{"body":"web", "score": 4, "tags": "java"}
{"body":"web", "score": 6, "tags": "java"}
{"body":"web", "score": 10, "tags": "php"}
{"body":"web", "score": 15, "tags": "ruby"}
{"body":"web", "score": 8, "tags": "php"}
```

Shard 2:

```
{"body":"web", "score": 4, "tags": "php"}
{"body":"web", "score": 6, "tags": "php"}
{"body":"web", "score": 3, "tags": "python"}
{"body":"web", "score": 9, "tags": "c#"}
{"body":"web", "score": 10, "tags": "python"}
{"body":"web", "score": 3, "tags": "php"}
{"body":"web", "score": 5, "tags": "ruby"}
{"body":"web", "score": 12, "tags": "javascript"}
{"body":"web", "score": 1, "tags": "python"}
{"body":"web", "score": 3, "tags": "java"}
```

On each shard, the tags buckets will look like this (ordered by `max(doc.score)`):

Shard 1:

```
ruby: 1 doc, max(doc.score) = 15
javascript: 1 doc, max(doc.score) = 10
php: 3 docs, max(doc.score) = 8
java: 3 docs, max(doc.score) = 6
python: 1 doc, max(doc.score) = 3
c#: 1 doc, max(doc.score) = 2
```

Shard 2:

```
javascript: 1 doc, max(doc.score) = 12
python: 3 docs, max(doc.score) = 10
c#: 1 doc, max(doc.score) = 9
php: 3 docs, max(doc.score) = 6
ruby: 1 doc, max(doc.score) = 5
java: 1 doc, max(doc.score) = 3
```

Only the first 5 are going to be returned to the coordinating node, which will recombine all buckets and re-order them again and only take the top 5, which yields these final buckets:

```
ruby: 2 docs, max(doc.score) = 15
javascript: 2 doc, max(doc.score) = 12
python: 4 docs, max(doc.score) = 10
php: 6 docs, max(doc.score) = 8
java: 3 docs, max(doc.score) = 6
```

So, as you can see the execution order is intertwined. The bucketing and ordering happens once on each shard and then again on the coordinating node. But it's not like first the order of the buckets are computed, then the buckets, etc... It all happens pretty much at the same time and bucketing/ordering is also performed first in a distributed way and finally everything is centralized, similar to what map/reduce does, in ES it's called scatter/gather.

Comment: Thank you. It is much clearer now. Please take a look at this link: https://ibb.co/PW9YdcZ. Is it the correct order in which the code is executed? It seems that the "order" part is just skipped?

Comment: It is not about the returned response. I just don't quite understand the execution order. But thank you!

Comment: I've provided an example and longer explanation on how it works.